# Shower temperature hot or freezing

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, heating, water-circulating-heating

Our gas powered shower has been gradually needing an increase in temperature over the last few months in order to have a warm shower. Originally a 32 degree shower was perfect, but gradually we have had to increase this to have a normal warm shower. Currently the temperature gauge is at 50 degrees and won't go any further. Within a day or so, we will be having cold showers.

I've tried re-pressurising the boiler, and all seems normal there. Water coming from taps are normal temperatures.

What else could it be?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the make and model of the shower heater? Where in the world are you? (BTW, when I read "gas powered shower" I thought of a two-stroke engine with a pull start...)

Comment: I assume these temperatures are Celsius. Does the shower have its own point of use water heater which is natural gas fired or is it using centrally heated water? What kind of shower valves do you have, one which meters hot and cold separately or a single handle (called in the US an 'anti-scald' valve)? If the former, you should be able to get hot water from the shower by opening only the hot valve. If the latter, I would expect that since you are getting hot water from other taps that the anti-scald valve is out of adjustment.